# Wordpress - Get Posts with Category data

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg

i have a question about improving my solution.

For my task i build a Gutenberg block which shows the latest 5 Posts. This Posts show also the Category Name in the Frontend part which have different styling each.

so I'm using the get_post() function to get all Posts, but there comes no Categories which is the reason i also used wp_get_post_categories() function.

This works fine , i used a foreach in a foreach to get my results. But it kinda feel Hardcoded especially the checking if Category "News" or "informative" is used is definitely hard coded.

is there a better solution how can i archive it that i can get the Posts with there bonded Post categories?

this was the best i can get for now and it works but im not happy with this solution.

my code:

```
...

$post = get_posts(
     [
        'posts_per_page' => 5,
     ]
);

...

ob_start();

some echos for html 

...

            foreach ($post AS $p)
            {

                $category = wp_get_post_categories($p->ID);
                foreach ($category AS $cat)
                {
                    echo '<div>';
                    echo '<div class="blog-image">';
                    echo '<img alt="" content="'.get_the_post_thumbnail($p->ID).'">';
                    echo '</div>';
                    echo '<div class="blog-data">';
                    echo '<div class="data-top">';
                    if(get_cat_name((int) $cat) === 'News')
                    {
                        echo '<div class="blog-type"><span class="news">'.get_cat_name((int) $cat).'</span></div>';

                    }elseif (get_cat_name((int) $cat) === 'Informative')
                    {
                        echo '<div class="blog-type"><span class="informative">'.get_cat_name((int) $cat).'</span></div>';
                    }
                    echo '<h3 class="blog-title">'.$p->post_title.'</h3>';
                    echo '</div>';
                    echo '<div class="data-bottom">';
                    echo '<div class="blog-info">';
                    echo '<p class="blog-date">'.date("d F Y", strtotime( $p->post_date)).'</p>';
                    echo '<div class="blog-link"><a href='.$p->guid.' >Read more</a></div> ';
                    echo '</div>';
                    echo '</div>';
                    echo '</div>';
                    echo '</div>';

                }
                echo '<br/>';
            }

...

more echos to close all html tags

    return ob_get_clean();
```

here is also how it should look:

[image]

Comment: You can directly access the category title by `$cat->name` instead of using `get_cat_name((int) $cat)`

Comment: @hemnathmouli this is not working because $cat is only an integer at this moment. with the get_cat_name( int $cat_id ) function i've getting the name